# XAMPP - portcheck.bat実行でNo ending delimiter '-' found というエラー

Tags: php, xampp

XAMPP をインストールして、 XAMPP でインストールされたアプリケーションがデフォルトで使用するポート番号がフリーかどうかを調べるため、 `C\install\portcheck.bat` を実行してみました。

すると以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

> Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '-' found in C:\xampp\install\portcheck.php on line 13

これは、 `portcheck.php` ファイルの13行目・・・の

```
$port = preg_replace("-", '', $argv[1]);
```

で発生しているものです。

多分、 `"-"` の前後に何か必要なのかと思い、 `"/"` を前後に入れて観ましたが、以前としてエラーが発生しています。これでは、ポート番号の空きの確認が出来ません。

誰か、この解決方法をご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授してください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 確かに `preg_replace()` の場合、パターン文字列はデリミタ文字で囲む必要があります。「"/"を前後に入れて観ましたが…」とありますが、`port = preg_replace("/-/", '', $argv[1]);` とした、という事でよろしいですか？

Comment: はい、実は、port=preg_replace("/-/", '', $argv[1]);
と入力した時、おそらく、入力の仕方が悪かったようです。
じぶんのミスでした。再確認してみたら、うまくいきました。
ありがとうございました。